# Manual table in R-Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

In R Markdown, how can I manually create such a long table as in the picture below (word screenshot)? The table goes over several pages and the first column contains texts that require a linebreak (PDF)

I was trying to do it like this:

```
| Column1                              | Column2    | Column3  | Column4 |
| -------------------------------------|-----------:| --------:| -------:|
| Some very long text...               |            |          |         |
```

However, formatting gets very troublesome as I cannot use a line breaks. Furthermore, in my PDF the columns start overlapping.

[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you considered creating a data frame and then outputting your table in your r-markdown using a function like `knitr::kable`?

Comment: If you're tagging both [tag:r] and [tag:r-markdown], I'd think that `knitr::kable` is the logical first step (otherwise it's just [tag:markdown], I'd think, not [tag:r]). I haven't tried it yet, what happens when you do that? Do you need to work in support for LaTeX's `longtable`?

Comment: Thanks everyone. It's simple text and not a data frame.

Comment: You want the text in table form, I think the best way to do that is create a data frame and pass that to `kable`.

Comment: But can I mark certain rows as titles using kable? (see image)

Comment: I do not see any rows that are titles in your image. Can you point one out specifically?

Comment: "Qualitätsmanagement" should be a title for the items below. That's why it is written in blue. There are more titles not shown.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a code chunk like this:

````
```{r}
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
data.frame(Column1 = c("YOUR", "TEXT", "HERE"),
           Column2 = NA,
           Column3 = NA, 
           Column4 = NA) |>
  knitr::kable()
```
````

Which will produce:

[image]

---

The `kable` function itself will output the markdown table (if you run it in the console instead of knitting the file):

```
|Column1 |Column2 |Column3 |Column4 |
|:-------|:-------|:-------|:-------|
|YOUR    |NA      |NA      |NA      |
|TEXT    |NA      |NA      |NA      |
|HERE    |NA      |NA      |NA      |
```